# AudioManager - difference between two methods

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager

What is the difference between calling `AudioManager.setRingerMode` to calling `AudioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, ...)`

What does the documentation mean by "Ringer mode"? I'm pretty sure it is the phone ringer mode. Then how does it differ from calling `setStreamMute` with `STREAM_VOICE_CALL`?

If it is not the phone ringer mode, then what is it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used the audio stream on the android platform, however, based on reading the documentation, I think setRingerMode will affect how the phone reacts to incoming calls. For example, AudioManager.setRingerMode(RINGER_MODE_SILENT) will disable vibrations and sound when an incoming call is received.

However, AudioManager.setStreamMute seems to control more than just the audio stream for phone rings.

From the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#STREAM_VOICE_CALL

I think that AudioManager.setRingerMode(RINGER_MODE_SILENT) will act the same way as AudioManager.setStreamMute(STREAM_RING, true).

I think the best way to see what the difference is (nd to see if what I am saying is true) would be to write a small program that tests the two features.

Comment: I've read this documentation many many times. But ok I'll try to check it out and see the difference

Comment: Yes, both do the same. But when using setRingerMode it also put the silent/vibrate sign at the top, when using setStreamMute it does not. Thanks for the idea to test it :)